# The Simplest Variadic Function

Tags: haskell, variadic-functions

How can I make this happen

```
assert toList 1 2 3 == [1, 2, 3]
```

I looked at

https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Varargs

http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/03/01/how-haskell-printf-works/

http://gotoanswer.stanford.edu/how_to_write_a_haskell_function_that_takes_a_variadic_function_as_an_argument-9197054/

http://paczesiowa.blogspot.de/2010/03/polyvariadic-primefib-problem.html

But I dont grasp it yet (still to much to junior with Haskell)

My attempt so far

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}

class ToVector r where
    process :: Int -> r

instance ToVector Int where
    process = id

instance ToVector r => ToVector (Int -> r) where
    process s = \v -> process v
```

Was greeted with this

```
*Main> process 1 2 3

<interactive>:158:1:
Could not deduce (ToVector (a0 -> a1 -> t))
  arising from the ambiguity check for ‘it’
from the context (ToVector (a -> a2 -> t), Num a2, Num a)
  bound by the inferred type for ‘it’:
             (ToVector (a -> a2 -> t), Num a2, Num a) => t
  at <interactive>:158:1-13
The type variables ‘a0’, ‘a1’ are ambiguous
When checking that ‘it’
  has the inferred type ‘forall a a1 t.
                         (ToVector (a -> a1 -> t), Num a1, Num a) =>
                         t’
Probable cause: the inferred type is ambiguous
*Main>
```

Any help and loads of explanation are very welcome

Comment: The error refers to code outside your snippet. You're going to have to add more for us to help you.

Comment: Really not. I just have a few Pragmas at the beginning of the code but thats really it. Obviously I load the module via :l mymod.hs into ghci

Comment: That particular error just seems to be an polymorphism error; Just try process (1::Int) (2::Int) (3::Int) and see how that goes (the type checker can't prove by itself that 1,2 or 3 should be `Int`), Also, if you're new to haskell keep your hands off stuff like this. I've been using haskell for a couple of years and never needed anything like that.

Comment: Your first code snippet indicates that you want a function with a type like `Int -> Int -> ... -> [Int]`; i.e. produce a list of `Int`s. But `process` is producing an `Int`. Also note that the inductive case (the second instance) simply throws away `s`; you're writing a variadic function that ignores all its arguments except the last one. If you turn on `-Wall`, you'll get a warning that `s` is unused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example [here](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Varargs) demonstrates how to use your code. The problem (correctly identified by @Cubic) is polymorphism. In particular, you can see in the example code calls the method *with a type*:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do printAll 5 "Mary" "had" "a" "little" "lamb" 4.2
          printAll 4 3 5
```

You need to do the same:

```
foo :: Int
foo = process (1 :: Int) (2 :: Int) (3 :: Int)
```

This specifies the type of `process`, namely to `Int -> Int -> Int -> Int`. You also need to specify the type of the numbers (unlike the example above) because you only made an instance for `Int`s, while `1` can be any `Num` type.

Comment: hmm still doesnt work. `process 1 :: Int` will work but `process 1 :: Int 2 :: Int` wont work and neither `process (1 :: Int) (2 :: Int)`

Comment: You need to annotate both the input and output types in this situation; note that Eric provided a signature for `foo` as well as for all the numbers. In a one-liner, you need to have `(process (1 :: Int) (2 :: Int)) :: Int`. (The outermost parentheses are unnecessary; I just wanted to illustrate the low precedence of `::`.)

Comment: hey thanks. that worked!

however ;-) Obviously I would like to have that without all that additional type hints.

Comment: You don't have to have all the extra type annotations - you can instead opt to have defaulting pick the types for you. Simply change the second instance declaration to `instance (int ~ Int, ToVector r) => ToVector (int -> r) where ...`. Then, `process 1 2 3 :: Int` compiles and prints "3". Of course, you still always need to have the terminal type.